# New tables don't appear in navigation bar

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm just starting to learn MS Access (2013).  I've been following some tutorials, and so far so good, but I've run into a snag.  When I create a new table and save it, the new table does not appear in the navigation bar on the left.  This means that if I close the tab, I can't find the table again to reopen it.

Now, I've noticed that the problem is fixed if I close MS Access entirely, and then reopen my database... but I don't want to have to do this every time I create a new table.  What is going wrong?  How can I fix this?

Comment: Continuing on with my tutorial, it seems this holds true for any object I create, whether it be a table, query, form, or report.  I have to quit access and reopen it for any new object to show up in the navigation pane.

Comment: With the navigation pane open, and the ribbon displayed, I just clicked the CREATE tab, then clicked Table. I was instantly into Table1 in datasheet mode, with the new Table1 showing in the navigation pane. Then I tried CREATE > Table Design to open a new table in design mode. This time, no table name appeared in the Navigation panel until I completed my table design and saved the new table. But it did appear then.  What are you doing differently?

Comment: I uploaded a video of my screen as I create two tables and a query, then close access and reopen.  You can view it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u73D38laItw

Comment: Thanks for the video. I wouldn't have believed it if I hadn't seen it! Does the same thing happen if you work with an existing database from somewhere else? Or if you create a new database from a template? (such as Desktop Lending Library)

Comment: I created a new database from the northwind template, and nothing showed up in the navigation bar.  I created a table, saved it, and then saved the database.  Then everything popped into the navigation bar.  I then added another table, and it did not show up in the navigation bar until I closed access and reloaded it.

This is really weird!  I -know- this isn't the expected behavior, and I just can't understand what might be causing it!

Comment: I've been using Access for 20 years, and the Navigation Pane since 2007. I've come across lots of quirks and bugs in Access, but this is not something I've seen. Just last week, a client had a problem where numbers on a subform would no longer show a total, even though it had been working fine for months. It was caused by some recent Office update that was installed automatically, and the solution was to do a reboot. I've found other posts about your problem: (see next comment)

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/Q_28561686.html suggests doing an installation repair. I recommend doing that. It also gives instructions on doing a recompile of a specific project, which is not your problem but you should know how to do it. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3551ba70-fe88-41b0-a213-46665ae263a4 discusses the problem in Access 2010, but without a solution. That's all I've got! ...Tom

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, use refresh (F5).

I have had the same issue in the later versions of Access (2007 and later). Although it does not appear to be in any menus/ribbons...with any object selected in the Navigation Pane, refresh (F5) will make newly-created-but-invisible tables and queries visible. Dave

Answer (score 0):

try this. First copy the database and back it up. Then click "Compact and Repair Database". This worked for me. Sometime old database get wacky

Answer (score 0):

Go to <kbd>Options</kbd>, <kbd>Current Database</kbd>, and then <kbd>Navigation Options</kbd>. Check <kbd>Show System Options</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used the
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow command
Example:

Dim tds As TableDefs
Dim td As TableDef

Set tds = CurrentDb.TableDefs

' new table
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(*TableName*)

' add field to new table (repeat)
Set ff = td.CreateField(*FieldName*, *FieldType*, *FieldLength*)
td.Fields.Append ff

' add table to tabledefs collection
tds.Append td
tds.Refresh

' make the new table visible
**RefreshDatabaseWindow**

' close object
Set tds = Nothing

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.